# Objective C - IOS - Property not found on object of type - when accessing object variables

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a UIView which is connected to a UITableView containing a list of shop items and populated by an array of data which is associated to an object class (shopObjects).

here is my shop objects H file -

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface shopObjects : NSObject



@property(strong) NSString *shopITitle;
@property(strong) NSString *shopIGroup;
@property(strong) NSString *shopIDesc;
@property(strong) NSString *shopIPrice;
@property Boolean offer;


-(id)initWithshopITitle:(NSString *)shopITitleD shopIGroup:(NSString *)shopIGroupD shopIDesc: (NSString *)shopIDescD shopIPrice:(NSString *)shopIPriceD offer:(Boolean )offerD;


@end
```

Shop Object . M file

```
#import "shopObjects.h"

@implementation shopObjects

-(id)initWithshopITitle:(NSString *)shopITitleD shopIGroup:(NSString *)shopIGroupD shopIDesc:(NSString *)shopIDescD shopIPrice:(NSString *)shopIPriceD offer:(Boolean )offerD{
self= [super init];
if(self){
    self.shopITitle = shopITitleD;
    self.shopIGroup = shopIGroupD;
    self.shopIDesc = shopIDescD;
    self.shopIPrice = shopIPriceD;
    self.offer = (offerD);



}
return self;


}


@end
```

this is my view controller .h file -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "shopObjects.h"

@interface shopVCSelectionViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *shopResScroller;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ShopItemTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *ShopItemDesc;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ShopItemPrice;

@end
```

and VC .m file -

```
#import "shopVCViewController.h"

@interface shopVCViewController ()

@end

@implementation shopVCViewController



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization




  }
  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//Set Scroller
[self.shopScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.shopScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1100)];
 self.title = @"Shop";
 self.shopArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 x PT session - £25",@"3 for 2 PT sessions     - £50 ",@"1 x Running Club - £15",@"1 x PT session",   nil];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.shopArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier      forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text=[self.shopArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I am trying to link up the labels/text fields with the relevant object variables - but the shopObjects object / associated variables dont appear in the predictive text and I get the following property not found error - I've no idea why!  Can anyone offer some advice please?

[image]

Comment: Are the propertied connected to the UI objects in Interfacebuilder?  BTW, the Apple naming conventions in Objective-C are for classes to start with a capital letter.

Comment: Please copy/paste the (relevant) code instead of screenshots. That makes it much easier for others to search for potential problems in your code.

Comment: I cannot see a property `shopITitle` in your *view controller*...

Comment: It seems that there is no  shopITitle property in your shopVCSelectionViewController. Also, use lowercase for property names and in your init use _propertyName = propertyValue.

Comment: There is no property for ShopTitle in the viewController

Comment: thanks guys - that screenshot was confusingly misleading - ive added the actual code - for some reason I cant access the shopObjects object or its properties in my .m file despite its header file being included..

Comment: note taken @Zaph re the naming conventions - out of interest would Apple be picky enough to reject and app for that - or is its simply a standard to stick to?

Comment: No, Apple will not reject an app but there are two main reasons for following conventions: 1) To others can easily understand your code. 2) The LLVM compiler and analyzer rely on certain naming conventions for error/warning messages and ARC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not inherit `shopObjects` in your viewController. It is a separate object.You need to create a variable of type `shopObjects`, set its properties and then call that. e.g.

```
shopVcSelectionViewController.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) shopObjects *shopObject;




shopVcSelectionViewController.m

...
self.shopItemTitle.text = self.shopObject.shopTitle
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is in an instance method of the class shopSelectionViewController.
A shopSelectionViewController has a property shopItemTitle, but not a shopITitle property.

This line

```
self.shopItemTitle.text = self.shopITitle;
```

Does not make sense.

If you are trying to fetch a title from an object of class "shopObjects", then you would need something like this:

```
shopObjects *someShopObject = //code to fetch a shopObject
self.shopItemTitle.text = someShopObject.shopITitle;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll also see this error if you have an object instance which is the same name as a class, and you mistakenly operate on the class, not your instance (thanks, Xcode auto-complete).

For example, suppose that you have a view controller `SetSignsViewController` and you create an instance of the view controller called `setSignsViewController`:

```
SetSignsViewController *setSignsViewController =
    (SetSignsViewController *) uiNavigationController.topViewController;
```

You want to set the name of a property called `openHouseLocation`:

```
SetSignsViewController.openHouseLocation = self.openHouseLocation;
```

This yields `Property 'openHouseLocation' not found on object of type 'SetSignsViewController'` because you're operating on `SetSignsViewController`, not `setSignsViewController` (first letter should be `s`, not `S`). What you really meant to do was:

```
setSignsViewController.openHouseLocation = self.openHouseLocation;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to `@synthesize` the variables in .m file of ShopObjects.

Comment: Since Xcode 4.4 (LLVM Compiler 4.0) the properties are synthesized automatically by the compiler, if necessary.